# jQuery .css() method – is it possible to change the default pixel unit?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to use the following code to add some height to a div:

```
    $('div').css("height", "+=50");
```

The above code will add 50 pixels to the div. How do I add a value using em units?

Comment: `.css()` seems to always calculates in pixels when using `+=` it does however respect your units when simply assigning the height: `$('div').css("height", "50em"); // <-- will work and use em units` ` $('div').css("height", "+=50em"); //<-- will not work and always add 50px`

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, unfortunately I need to _add_ a height value in this case, otherwise your suggestion would have worked well.

Comment: oh. I didn't mean that as a solution . I was only shown the other way to demonstrate the behaviour. Sorry for the mix-up :)

Comment: No problem at all, I appreciate your input. Thanks

Comment: I totally forgot. +1 as this is a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just add the format following the number and jquery will NOT figure out the rest. This will not work, jQuery loves pixels and wont convert so having `"+=50em"` wont cut it.

Here the fix for ems, It's a sloppy fix but it works.

```
$("div").css("height", ($("div").height()+50)+"em");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/npZCB/4/

> *`FrançoisWahl`: As an additional note `.height()` gives you the height without padding, borders and margins. To include padding use `.innerHeight()`, to include padding and borders use `.outerHeight()` and to include padding borders and margins use `.outerHeight(true)`. Just thought I add this in case you needed it.

Comment: Correct. Just wanted to add that this can be done anywhere you give a measurement in CSS.

Comment: `1em` is aprx `16px`, so one would assume that when applying `50px` it is different than `50em`. Using your fiddle, add a second `div`, increase the first `div` by `50em` and the second one by `50px`. They end up the same height. I'm assuming this is either because your fiddle has no default height or because `css()` might simply add 50 in what ever default units. See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5DByu/) as example. The alerts also show both divs end up the same height. Tested in Chrome, FF and IE.

Comment: I believe this is because the .css() method in jQuery always returns values in px units (by design). So, when using +=, it will automatically assume you are adding 50 px units, rather than 50 em units.

Comment: Thank you all for contributing. @CodyBonney, does that mean that there is no way to override it?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl you seem to be correct – and in similar tests these were the results I was getting. Simply adding the unit, as CezarisLT suggests, did not make it use ems.

Comment: @Sam Check out my updated answer, its a bit messy but it works.

Comment: @CezarisLT, this works great. However for my use I need to have an `ing` in the div instead of just text, with the height set to `auto` in the stylesheet. Please see this fiddle (link: http://jsfiddle.net/npZCB/4/). The only difference between the two divs is one has the `height: auto;`. Is there a way to get it to work with `height: auto;`?

Comment: (I appreciate this is a bit of a separate question, so I've marked your answer as accepted for the above. Thanks.)

Comment: @CezarisLT, sorry, my fiddle link didn't work correctly in my last post (still getting the hang of this…). Please see http://jsfiddle.net/approach/npZCB/8/

Comment: @CezarisLT: I removed my down vote and upvoted instead as you now have a working solution. Nice one.

Comment: @Sam: As an additional note `.height()` gives you the height without padding, borders and margins. To include padding use `.innerHeight()`, to include padding and borders use `.outerHeight()` and to include padding borders and margins use `.outerHeight(true)`. Just thought I add this in case you needed it.

Comment: Doesn't this confuse units? It seems to take the original `.height()` in pixels and then **treat those pixels as em's** (in addition to adding 50ems to them). So instead of turning 1em to 51em (1+50), it turns 1em to something like 66em (16+50). That is, when font-size is 16px 1em would equal 16px.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly cleaner fix that I use!

```
function update_css(target_element, css_attribute, value, unit) {
    $(target_element).css(css_attribute, [value + unit]);
};
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/npZCB/10/)

Square brackets are rarely used, but bare in mind they often come in handy when jquery doesn't understand what you're trying to say!

Comment: The brackets create an array, which jQuery coalesces to a string. Because the + operator also coalesces to a string anyway, there is functionally no difference with or without the brackets: http://jsfiddle.net/npZCB/11/